# How to set the SNAPSHOT isolation level in Spring

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, isolation-level

Could anyone help me understand how to set isolation level to `SNAPSHOT` in Spring's XML config?

I am taking over a project used to be developed by someone else and in certain cases we get deadlocks when working with database. I've verified that despite the DB isolation level of `SNAPSHOT`, when the application issues a request, isolation level for that transaction changes to `READ_COMMITTED`. According to my brief research, if not set explicitly, hibernate uses the `DEFAULT` isolation, which for SQLServer 2012 is `READ_COMMITTED`.

Unfortunately, I am not an expert in either Spring or Hibernate, so I'll just give the configs that seem relevant:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/ds</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${nn.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${nn.hibernate.showSQL}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${nn.hibernate.generatestatics}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${nn.hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${nn.hibernate.batchsize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${nn.hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${nn.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>


<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NNDBException"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NNDBException"/>
        <tx:method name="checkFor*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NNDBException"/>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>


<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

While researching possible solutions I also learnt that setting `hibernate.connection.isolation` when `DataSource` is provided is not effective.

From there I got to [this example](http://henningpetersen.com/post/1/custom-isolation-levels-with-jta-and-spring) where `IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter` is used to set isolation level on each instance of `Connection`. The configs became this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/ds</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter">
            <property name="targetDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="isolationLevel" value="4096" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property> 
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${nn.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${nn.hibernate.showSQL}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${nn.hibernate.generatestatics}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${nn.hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${nn.hibernate.batchsize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${nn.hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${nn.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>


<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NNDBException"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NNDBException"/>
        <tx:method name="checkFor*" read-only="false" rollback-for="NNDBException"/>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>


<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

where I set isolation level to `4096` in `sessionFactory`. However, this is where I hit the wall: `IllegalArgumentException: Only isolation constants allowed`, which I presume are `DEFAULT`, `READ_UNCOMMITTED`, `READ_COMMITTED`, `REPEATABLE_READ`, and `SERIALIZABLE`.

Is there a proven way to set isolation level to `SNAPSHOT` (or `4096`) in the context of the configs that I have?

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are obtaining your data source from JNDI, you will need to find a way to configure the isolation level in the JNDI registry.  This may or may not be possible depending on the JNDI implementation you are using.  Even if you had a local (defined in the XML) data source, different data sources have different mechanisms for configuring the isolation level.  For example, Atomikos allows setting an integer value for the isolation level, whereas HikariCP only takes a string.  Therefore, you would be able to use `4096` as a possible isolation level with Atomikos but not with HikariCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter` checks for the standard isolation level codes, which is a clear limitation (I suggest you file a Spring JIRA issue for this).

To work around it, you need to extend the `IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter` class:

```
public class CustomIsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter extends IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter {

    private final Integer customIsolationLevel;

    public CustomIsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter(Integer customIsolationLevel) {
        this.customIsolationLevel = customIsolationLevel;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer getIsolationLevel() {
        return customIsolationLevel != null ? customIsolationLevel : super.getIsolationLevel();
    }
}
```

and use this `dataSource` instead:

```
<bean class="my.package.CustomIsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter">
    <constructor-arg value="4096"/>
</bean>
```